# I am not getting all the products after executing my query

Tags: magento-1.9, product, database

> After executing my query i got several products (SKUs) but it is not
>   displaying all the products that are stored in the database.

Take a look at this picture:

[image]

**How do i know that?** Well, I put a random SKU in the MAGENTO application, then i clicked on "search" and the product appeared.

I tried to find that SKU in MYSQL but it was not there:

Take a look:

[image: image2]

This is my query:

```
SELECT main.entity_id,main.sku,code_brand.value AS code_brand

FROM catalog_product_entity AS main 

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS code_brand
ON main.entity_id = code_brand.entity_id

WHERE code_brand.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id 
    FROM eav_attribute 
    WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'code_brand'
    AND `entity_type_id` = (
        SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
    )
)
```

What is happening here? Am i missing anything?

*This is the MAGENTO database diagram:*

[image: image3]

EDIT:

> How can i get all products with status = disabled or enabled?

I've been searching and i found this:

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
    WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 2
```

How can i modify my code in order to obtain that?

Comment: It looks like you have a limitation to 1000 rows in your SQL client set. Check the settings. Try select count(*) from ... insted of listing the fields that should give you the number of products your query would return without limit set. To change/delete the limit check the manual of your SQL client

Comment: @HelgeB Yeah, you are right!. Thank you, buddy :)

Comment: Dude, how can i know if a product is enabled or disabled? I mean, for example: i want to obtain all the products with "status = disabled". How can i do that? Take a look, i have edited the question. I tried to do that buy i failed :(

Comment: @HelgeB No, it is not working. I was not able to get ALL the products. Take a look: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260305/not-getting-all-the-products-after-executing-my-query-they-appear-in-the-applic