# Not getting all the products after executing my query (they appear in the application)

Tags: magento-1.9

> Yesterday i tried to obtain all products from MAGENTO database. I did
>   a query and i thought it was working BUT i was wrong.

I put a random SKU in the MAGENTO application, then i clicked on "search" and the product appeared but that SKU did not apprear in my query:

[image]

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT main.sku, code_brand.value AS code_brand,option_value_brand.value

FROM catalog_product_entity AS main 
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int AS code_brand ON main.entity_id = code_brand.entity_id
JOIN eav_attribute_option option_brand on option_brand.attribute_id = code_brand.attribute_id and option_brand.option_id = code_brand.value
JOIN eav_attribute_option_value option_value_brand on option_brand.option_id = option_value_brand.option_id

WHERE code_brand.attribute_id = (
    SELECT attribute_id 
    FROM eav_attribute 
    WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'code_brand'
    AND `entity_type_id` = (
        SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'
    )
);
```

Whats going on here?

**EDIT: What about `store_id` = 0 and `store_id` = 1?**

Can please help me to obtain ALL the products?

What should i modify?

*This is the MAGENTO database diagram:*

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what your requirements are, but I try to explain you what might be your problem:
If you want't to get all the products - no matter if the attribute `code_brand` is set or not, you have to use join left consequently in your sql statement. Now I assume that either the SKU you have used to filter the result of your SQL client is from a product with no attribute selected for `code_brand` or your SQL client is still limiting the result set.

So here is the SQL statement to get all products and join the attribute value, if a value is set (otherwise you will get NULL in that column):

```
SELECT main.sku, code_brand.value AS code_brand,option_value_brand.value
FROM catalog_product_entity AS main 
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute attribute_brand on attribute_brand.attribute_code = 'code_brand' and attribute_brand.entity_type_id = 4
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int code_brand ON main.entity_id = code_brand.entity_id and code_brand.attribute_id = attribute_brand.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option option_brand on option_brand.attribute_id = code_brand.attribute_id and option_brand.option_id = code_brand.value
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value option_value_brand on option_brand.option_id = option_value_brand.option_id;
```

You can add `where main.sku = '[what-ever-sku-you-want-to-filter]'` to get the specific row for that sku.

I hope that helps.

**Edit**
Assuming you want to join the varchar attribute code_business_unit to the above statement use this SQL (I've removed the columns for the option ids from the statement because you don't need them)

```
SELECT main.sku, option_value_brand.value AS code_brand, code_business_unit.value as code_business_unit
FROM catalog_product_entity AS main 
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute attribute_brand on attribute_brand.attribute_code = 'code_brand' and attribute_brand.entity_type_id = 4
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute attribute_business_unit on attribute_business_unit.attribute_code = 'code_business_unit' and attribute_brand.entity_type_id = 4
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_int code_brand ON main.entity_id = code_brand.entity_id and code_brand.attribute_id = attribute_brand.attribute_id
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option option_brand on option_brand.attribute_id = code_brand.attribute_id and option_brand.option_id = code_brand.value
LEFT JOIN eav_attribute_option_value option_value_brand on option_brand.option_id = option_value_brand.option_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar code_business_unit ON main.entity_id = code_business_unit.entity_id and code_business_unit.attribute_id = attribute_business_unit.attribute_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!.
Why did you use *attribute_brand.entity_type_id = 4* ?
Should i use the  where condition from my code?

Comment: the entity_type_id of catalog_product is 4 in magento. Since this value never changes it's simpler to query that way than using `SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'`

Comment: Just a question: How would you change your code in order to get catalog_product_entity_varchar AS code_business_unit? What about the "where" condition from my code? Should i use it in your code?

Comment: You don't need the where condition, I have transformed that into left joins in order to get all products including those without attribute `code_brand` set. For a varchar attribute you need only the value from the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table. That means you can remove the last two joins from the statement in the answer and change the eav table corresponding from `_int` to `_varchar`, and of corse the attribute code :-)

Comment: But if i delete the last two columns i will not be able to see the option value, am i right?

Comment: varchar attributes do not have option values, the text is stored in the value field of the table

Comment: Dude, can you check this:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262130/obtain-all-orders-from-magento-b2b-without-success

Comment: Dude, how can i get those items that are enabled only? I am getting all products and i just want those that are enabled, not disabled! :(.
What is the condition?

Comment: I've tried without to obtain only the enabled items using your query. I think it is a field but i cannot find it :(

Comment: I tried to use this condition: *WHERE catalog_product_entity_int.value = 1* but it is not working properly :(