# Obtain all orders from MAGENTO B2B without success

Tags: magento-1.9

I wanted to get all orders **(B2B)** that are stored in MAGENTO database (using SQL) and obtain all the information about them (Items, price, transport information, current status, user information and so on)

I was trying something like this but this is not what i really want:

```
SELECT ord_items.name, ord_items.sku, ord_items.qty_ordered, ord_items.weight, ord_items.price
FROM sales_flat_order_item as ord_items
WHERE ord_items.product_type = 'configurable' OR ord_items.product_type = 'bundle';
```

Can help me with this?

This is the MAGENTO database diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about the order you will get from the table `sales_flat_order` while information at order line level you find in `sales_flat_order_item`. To get informations at order level and at order line item you have to join both tables.

```
select o.*, oi.* from sales_flat_order o
join sales_flat_order_item oi on o.entity_id = oi.order_id where oi.parent_item_id is null and ....
```

With this statement you will get all information from both tables please adapt it however you need it. The condition `parent_item_id is null` is to avoid double listing configurale products, which are stored twice (one line for parent and one for the child).
Please note: you will get for each order as many rows as there are order lines.

If you need one row per order you have to add `group by oi.order_id` to your statement and `sum` before the numeric order_item columns you request in the statement.

Update example statement with carrier information:

Assuming you want to get the real order id (i.e. increment id), the status, ordered quantity and the total amount (incl. tax and shipping) for an order AND the skus and prices incl. tax for each order line
AND a carrier_code (if the order has been shipped and the tracking information has been updated), you may use the following statement:

```
select o.increment_id, o.status, o.base_grand_total, 
       o.total_qty_ordered, oi.sku, oi.price_incl_tax, t.carrier_code 
from sales_flat_order o
join sales_flat_order_item oi 
   on o.entity_id = oi.order_id 
left join sales_flat_shipment_track t 
   on o.entity_id = t.order_id -- left join here if you want also orders which are not yet shipped
where oi.parent_item_id is null
```

Please check the database table for other appropriate columns you need according to your requirement.

Comment: You rock!.Dude, for example: how would you change your code if you wanted to obtain the transport information (the carrier)?

Comment: Also, i dont fully understand how should i modify your code if i want to obtain the final price for each order *BUT* i want to see the prices of the different items for an specific order (Also, i want to see the order number). Do you get me?

Comment: If you need information for each item separately you will either have a row per order line in your statement and the order information (for example the order increment id or the order status) will appear in each of that order lines or you will have to run more than one statement - this depends on your requierement. I'll update my answer with an example which also contain the carrier information which is stored in another table `sales_flat_shipment_track`

Comment: Dude, what would you do if you wanted to obtain the date of each order? 
PS: i tried to do the *group by oi.order_id* but  i got an error :(

Comment: Also, i am getting NULL results in th field "carrier_code"

Comment: Date is created_at, carrier_code is null if the order has not been shipped yet and base_grand_total is the total order amount. I don't know what else you could mean with "final price"

Comment: Sorry, i mean: how can know what is *the price of sale for the public (PSP)*?
I think that every order has  transport name / transport code when it is created, am i wrong?

Comment: I don't know what your customizations are, but the Magento standard is that the carrier is assigned when something is shipped. You have also a field shipping_method where the method selected by customer in the checkout is stored, maybe you want that. Try the base_subtotal from the order table, that might be what you want. A "price" exists only at order line level since a product has a price but an order hasn't

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Dude, what about the *group by* part? i  think i am missing something because it is not working for me :/

Comment: What is the difference between *o.created_at and io.created_at*? they are returning the same date

Comment: There is usually no difference between created_at in the both tables since order head and order lines are created at the same time. I don't know your requirements and therefore I just can say what I have already told you: group by order_id and sum(oi.price_incl_tax) would give you the sum of all items prices of an order. But you can't have the price of a single item in the same row. So you have to make yor decision, choose fields according to your requirements.

Comment: Dude, can you check this?: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262138/obtain-all-the-information-related-to-a-customer

Comment: Dude, how can i find all the purchase orders stored in MAGENTO database? I've tried so many times without success :(

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you, what do you mean with "purchase orders"? `select * from sales_flat_order;` gives you all orders :-)

Comment: Not the order number, i mean.. the purchase order number :/

Comment: `select increment_id from sales_flat_order;` if you don't have some special customization in your system

Comment: Dude, could you please take a look at this?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268102/not-getting-the-information-about-orders-null-line-level