# Not getting the information about orders - NULL (line level)

Tags: magento-1.9

I've been trying without success to obtain the line level information about a specific order **but** i am getting the header information.

Take a look at this picture:

[image: example]

This is my query:

```
select o.increment_id, o.status, oi.price_incl_tax, t.carrier_code, o.created_at, oi.price_pvp, oi.created_at, o.shipping_instruction, o.payment_term
from sales_flat_order o
join sales_flat_order_item oi 
   on o.entity_id = oi.order_id 
left join sales_flat_shipment_track t 
   on o.entity_id = t.order_id 
where oi.parent_item_id is null
```

What's wrong? Can you please help me to solve this?

EDIT:

This is what i found in MYSQL:

[image]

*The problem here is that i do not understand how should i look into this in order to obtain what i need :/.*

Comment: `shipping_instruction`, `payment_term` are not fields of standard Magento in the `sales_flat_order` table. Therefore you should look into your customization if you would expect data in that fields - the SQL returns NULL because there is no data in that fields for the orders you have selected. Regarding the `carrier_code`: The tracking data is usually assigned to an order when something has been shipped, which might not be the case in your status `waiting_approval` (which again is not standard Magento but some customization). IMHO the SQL is correct and returns the data you have in database.

Comment: @HelgeB Thank you for replying, dude. I've edited my question. Have you got any idea about it? What should i do?

Comment: You have the data of order lines ( `sales_flat_order_item` table) in your SQL joined to the order head (`sales_flat_order` table) data. For example the SKU comes from there. So I don't really understand what your problem is - it's not clear what you are looking for and what is not working. Again, your SQL is correct and returns oder lines joined to order head data.

Comment: @HelgeB I think my query it is supposed to show the line information for every order, right? Everytime that i execute it, it shows NULL in some fields:, i.e: shipping_information, payment methods and so on. Why? A guy told me that if it is returning NULL its because i am returning the HEADER information,NOT the LINE information :/

Comment: I can just repeat again what I have said already: you have order line and order head information joined. And your shipping_information and payment_methods (what ever that fields should be, they are not standard Magento) are order head information because you take them from sales_flat_order table. I can't tell you what's wrong with your custom data I just can say you can't get more data than you have in the database with SQL :-)

Comment: @HelgeB sorry, yeah.. you are right! :)
I love you buddy!

Comment: Hey dude! could you please check this?: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276984/order-sale-vs-purchase-order-in-magento-not-getting-the-difference