# order sale vs purchase order in Magento (not getting the difference)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, sales-order

I dont fully understand what is the difference between **Sale Order** and **Purchase Order** in MAGENTO.

In my system i have 4 tables that are related to the Sale Order and 4 tables that are related to the Purchase Order; i mean, everytime that an order or a purchase order is set in MAGENTO a row is created in one of these tables

**Sale Order tables:**

-Header_order (contains the header information of the order)

-order_information (contains the information of the different lines of the order)

-approvals (this table was created because a guy can approve or reject the different lines of the order)

**Purchase Order tables:**

-Purchase_order_header (contains the header information of the purchase order)

-Purchase_order_items (contains the information of the different items of the purchase table)

-Purchase_order_approvals (this table was created because a guy can approve or reject the different lines of the purchase order).

Could you please explain to me WHAT is the different between them? I dont get it

Thanks!

Comment: This are not standard Magento tables, therefore it's hard to guess what the difference can be. Therefore your question may be considered off topic for this board.

Comment: Have you got any idea about that? I am super lost :/
@HelgeB

Comment: @HelgeB https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/285837/validate-email-using-magento-1-9-not-way